# How to Skip 500 Internal Server Error and Continue Webscraping using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am Doing `Webscraping` using Python `BeautifulSoup`.

> Getting an Error 'HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error'.

Below is My Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pdb
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv
from urllib.error import HTTPError

for IPRD_ID in range(1,10):
   url = 'https://ipr.etsi.org/IPRDetails.aspx?IPRD_ID={}&IPRD_TYPE_ID=2&MODE=2'.format(IPRD_ID)
   page = urlopen(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
   table = soup.findAll('table', style="width:100%")
   try:
      for tr in table:
          a = (tr.get_text())
   except:
      print('exe')
```

As we have seen I am doing Using `range` function which Starts from 1 to 10.I checked code step by step.At `IPRD_ID=3` page server error is there no data.So its creating `500 Internal Error`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivIl3.png)

As we have seen no data so its coming error
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivIl3.png)

HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
we have seen one `IPRD_ID=3` which is having error,If i give more range 1 to 100 may have more error pages.So,I want help that how to skip like this pages and move forward for `webscraping`

Comment: Where is internal server error in this code ?

Comment: I guess the error appears at the urlopen(url) line? You can try to wrap the code starting from that line to the last line in your code snippet in a try catch. In the catch just simply log/print which site gave a 500 and then let it continue.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `urlopen(URL)` raises `urllib.error.HTTPError` exception. You can catch this exception directly, or more general-purpose exception like `class Exception(BaseException): pass`. Also, you can make delay between `HTTP` requests (This is extremely recommended in your case), as it is in my code...

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pdb
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv
from urllib.error import HTTPError

for IPRD_ID in range(1,10):
    url = 'https://ipr.etsi.org/IPRDetails.aspx?IPRD_ID={}&IPRD_TYPE_ID=2&MODE=2'.format(IPRD_ID)
    try:
        page = urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as exc:
        print('Something went wrong.')
        time.sleep(10) # wait 10 seconds and then make http request again
        continue
    else:
        print('if client get http response, start parsing.')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
        table = soup.findAll('table', style="width:100%")
        try:
            for tr in table:
                a = tr.get_text()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('Something went wrong during parsing !!!')
        finally:
            time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds if success, and then make HTTP request.
```

Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try catching the error code and continue if it encounters an error

```
for IPRD_ID in range(1,10):
    url = 'https://ipr.etsi.org/IPRDetails.aspx?IPRD_ID={}&IPRD_TYPE_ID=2&MODE=2'.format(IPRD_ID)
    try:
        page = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
        table = soup.findAll('table', style="width:100%")
        for tr in table:
            a = (tr.get_text())

    except  HTTPError, err:
        if err.code == 500:
            print ("Internal server error 500")
        else:
            print ("Some other error. Error code: ", err.code)
```